# Stripping "blog" from wordpress URLs with Regex

Tags: regex, wordpress

I've managed to get myself totally mired in the world of regex and could do with a hand out.

I've recently moved my wordpress install from just the /blog subdomain to the whole site so I need to strip /blog/ from all incoming urls except an exact match as /blog is still the blog.

For example I need:

```
http://foo.com/blog/bar
http://foo.com/blog/foobar/bar
foo.com/blog/bar
```

to all lose the /blog/ but I need

```
http://foo.com/blog
foo.com/blog
```

to keep theirs.

I'm using the wordpress Redirections plugin to manage this as it tracks 404 errors which put me on to this.

Can anyone help!?

Comment: Replacing `'/blog/'` with `'/'` should do the trick. You don't even need regex for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `\/blog\/(.+)` with `/$1`

Only replacing `/blog/` with `/` would also replace `http://foo.com/blog/`

**Update:**

> That works perfectly except that my previous previous post structure
>   was /y/m/d/postname. How would I strip that as well when it's present
>   but not affect the other redirect when it isn't?

In this case you could use `\/blog\/(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(.+))`.

Result:

```
url: http://foo.com/blog/2014/03/09/bar
$1: 2014/03/09/bar
$2: bar
```

**Update 2:**

In case you wanted to have both ways stripped use `\/blog\/(?:\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/)?(.+)`

Result:

```
url: http://foo.com/blog/bar
url: http://foo.com/blog/2014/03/09/bar
$1: bar

url: http://foo.com/blog/tag/sometag
$1: tag/sometag
```

Comment: That works perfectly except that my previous previous post structure was /y/m/d/postname. How would I strip that as well when it's present but not affect the other redirect when it isn't?

Comment: Hmmmm... that's stripping the blog but not the /2012/10/01/ in posts and not stripping anything blog/tag/2012. 

EDIT: pushed return too soon. This image shows my set up. Is it wrong? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25250818/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-12%20at%2014.21.41.png

Comment: @user3733863 that is why I added the `$2`. If you want it all stripped you use `/$2` as target. The newer pattern only matches the date ones. You can make that optional by adding a `?` after the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try simple replace()?. Unless I misunderstood the question, isn't the output shown the same as what you need?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "http://foo.com/blog/bar";
    String s1 = "http://foo.com/blog";
    System.out.println(s.replace("/blog/", "/"));
    System.out.println(s1.replace("/blog/", "/"));
}
```

O/P :

```
http://foo.com/bar
http://foo.com/blog
```

Comment: It needs to work as a 301 redirect? Don't think you can use that in a htaccess file.